# Extend Doctrine2 entities with annotations using Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

The application is using Zend Framework 3 with Doctrine2.
Me and my team are developing a system, which includes a "core" part, which will be update-able for all of our clients, and a "local" part, holding client-specific logic.

Let's take for example this entity definition of a currency, which have to be extended for a client with specific needs, say to add another field for enabling/disabling of the currency AND/OR change the entity repository\listener so that a new method can be added to it.

```
<?php

namespace Currency\Core\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Rizn\Doctrine\AbstractEntity;

/**
 * Class Currency
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Currency\Core\Entity\Repository\CurrencyRepository")
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"Currency\Core\Entity\Listener\CurrencyListener"})
 * @ORM\Table(name="Currency", options={"collate"="utf8_general_ci", "charset"="utf8"})
 */
class Currency extends AbstractEntity{

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    public $code;

    /**
     * @var float
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=8, scale=5)
     */
    public $coefficient;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    public $symbol;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    public $decimalPoint = ".";

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    public $thousandsSeparator = "";

    /**
     * @var bool
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    public $appendSymbol;

    /**
     * @var bool
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    public $isDefault;

}
```

How am I supposed to extend this entity and add more properties to it or change the annotations? The furthest I can get is defining and empty entity with class annotations which extends from the Core one:

```
<?php

namespace Currency\Local\Entity;

use Currency\Core;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class Currency
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Currency\Local\Repository\CurrencyRepository")
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"Currency\Local\Entity\Listener\CurrencyListener"})
 * @ORM\Table(name="Currency", options={"collate"="utf8_general_ci", "charset"="utf8"})
 */
class Currency extends Core\Entity\Currency{

}
```

The repositories follow the same logic - a local class, extending the core class. However, it does not seem quite right, because I cannot update the class annotations. Say I have to add a new index - impossible. I have to go through all of the clients' projects and add it manually. Plus, there is a lot of bloat code just for the sake of extending. And there are some classes that are not so likely to be extended.

Here is my current Doctrine configuration in the module.config.php of the Currency module:

```
"doctrine" => [
    "driver" => [
    __NAMESPACE__ . "_driver" => [
            "class" => AnnotationDriver::class,
            "cache" => "array",
            "paths" => [dirname(__DIR__) . "/src/" . __NAMESPACE__ . "/Entity"]
        ],
        "orm_default" => [
            "drivers" => [
                __NAMESPACE__ . "\\Entity" => __NAMESPACE__ . "_driver"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Is there any working solution for this, that I cannot find in the docs?